# Fiware Cygnus Handler Not Found

Tags: java, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have done a clean installation of Fiware (Orion ContextBroker, MongoDB, Java JDK & Cygnus) on a CentOS 6.9 machine. But i got a problem with Cygnus, i cant get him start. When i try anything, event the [Quick Start Guide Test](http://fiware-cygnus.readthedocs.io/en/0.13.0/quick_start_guide/index.html) i got the following error :

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler**

Do you know what the problem is? Thanks !

Cygnus log file :

```
time=2017-08-31T14:17:49.917Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp= | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[166] : Starting Cygnus, version 1.7.1.UNKNOWN
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.070Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.071Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=start | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider[61] : Configuration provider starting
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.074Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[133] : Reloading configuration file:/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_test.conf
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.083Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:test-sink
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.083Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:test_sink
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.083Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:test-sink
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.084Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[1016] : Processing:test-sink
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.084Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=addProperty | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration[930] : Added sinks: test-sink Agent: cygnusagent
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.098Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=validateConfiguration | msg=org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration[140] : Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [cygnusagent]
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.098Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=loadChannels | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[150] : Creating channels
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.108Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=create | msg=org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory[40] : Creating instance of channel test-channel type memory
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.114Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=loadChannels | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[205] : Created channel test-channel
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.115Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=create | msg=org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory[39] : Creating instance of source http-source, type org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.120Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=configure | msg=org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource[113] : Error while configuring HTTPSource. Exception follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.configure(HTTPSource.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:331)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.123Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=loadSources | msg=org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider[366] : Source http-source has been removed due to an error during configuration
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:156)
    at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.configure(HTTPSource.java:114)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:331)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource.configure(HTTPSource.java:102)
    ... 11 more
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.127Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=create | msg=org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory[40] : Creating instance of sink: test-sink, type: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionTestSink
time=2017-08-31T14:17:50.128Z | lvl=ERROR | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=run | msg=org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable[142] : Failed to load configuration data. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.FlumeException: Unable to load sink type: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionTestSink, class: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionTestSink
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.getClass(DefaultSinkFactory.java:69)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSinks(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:415)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:103)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:473)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionTestSink
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:359)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.getClass(DefaultSinkFactory.java:67)
    ... 11 more
time=2017-08-31T14:17:51.071Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2017-08-31T14:17:52.071Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2017-08-31T14:17:53.072Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2017-08-31T14:17:54.072Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
time=2017-08-31T14:17:55.072Z | lvl=INFO | corr= | trans= | srv= | subsrv= | comp=cygnusagent | op=main | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.nodes.CygnusApplication[289] : Waiting for valid Flume components references...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrionRestHandler` was the name of the Http handler in charge of parsing NGSI notifications until `0.13.0` version. From `1.0.0` its name is `NGSIRestHandler`.

The same occurs with the name of the sinks, a `OrionXXXSink` is now `NGSIXXXSink`.

Sinply replace the old names with the new ones if you are using a recent version of Cygnus.